# Update 163 A Records in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 163 A records I need to update the IP address for in an AWS route 53 hosted zone. Is there a good way to achieve this without having to type out individual JSON files or edit each record one by one?

Comment: What scripting languages do you know? If you have a format that's easy to ready, you could either invoke the SDK directly, or produce the output for the command-line tool.

Comment: Also, what format do you have the records in? Are they in a [zone file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating-import.html) format?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest managing them all in a CloudFormation stack